# Why is there no hyper-hypercohomology?

Tags: sheaf-cohomology, derived-categories

I am looking for a reference to answer the question in the title. Let me try to clarify a little what I mean:

If a single sheaf $\mathscr F$ has a resolution $\mathscr G^\bullet$ by not necessarily injective objects, then the usual cohomology of $\mathscr F$ is isomorphic to the hypercohomology of $\mathscr G^\bullet$: 
$$
H^i(X, \mathscr F) \cong \mathbb H^i(X,\mathscr G^\bullet).
$$

Now, if one was starting with a complex of sheaves $\mathscr F^\bullet$ and a "resolution" thereof, i.e. a complex of complexes $(\mathscr G^\bullet)^\bullet$, then one should touch on a concept that could be called hyper-hypercohomology.

Yet, I never heard of its existence and I'm pretty sure it does not give you anything new, as soon as you work in the derived category. I just find myself unable to pin down why exactly this is the case.

Any ideas anyone?

Answer (score 2):

You seem to suggest that hypercohomology arise only when you have a sheaf $\mathcal{F}$ and a resolution $\mathcal{G}^\bullet$ by non-necessarily acyclic sheaves. Well, sure $\mathbb{H}^i(X,\mathcal{G}^\bullet)$ is hypercohomology, but this is the same thing as $H^i(X,\mathcal{F})$ which is (not hyper) cohomology.

I would say that for hypercohomology, we would rather start with a complex $\mathcal{F}^\bullet$ which may **not** be quasi-isomorphic to a single object. For example, if $f:\mathcal{F\to G}$ is a morphism which is neither injective nor surjective, then this can be seen as complex concentrated in (homological) degree 1 and 0, and you can consider the hypercohomology $\mathbb{H}^i(X,\mathcal{F}\xrightarrow{f}\mathcal{G})$. This is interesting because it fits into a long exact sequence
$$...\to H^i(X,\mathcal{F})\to H^i(X,\mathcal{G})\to\mathbb{H}^i(X,\mathcal{F}\xrightarrow{f}\mathcal{G})\to H^{i+1}(X,\mathcal{F})\to ...$$

In this regard, when you have a complex of sheaves $\mathcal{F}^\bullet$, you don't need (except for some constructions of hypercohomology) to construct a bicomplex $\mathcal{G}^{\bullet,\bullet}$ to take "hyperhypercohomology".

---

Now you can ask the following question : if I have a bicomplex $\mathcal{F}^{\bullet,\bullet}$ (first quadrant for simplicity), but **not** necessarily a resolution of a single complex, what would be the natural extension of cohomology/hypercohomology for it ?

Well, as you realized, there is nothing new here : the natural extension would be hypercohomology of the total complex. Indeed :

- if $\mathcal{G}^{\bullet,\bullet}$ is column-wise (or row-wise) a resolution of a complex $\mathcal{F}^\bullet$, then $\mathcal{F}^\bullet\to\operatorname{Tot}^\bullet(\mathcal{G})$ is a quasi-isomorphism. So $\mathbb{H}^i(X,\mathcal{F}^\bullet)\simeq \mathbb{H}^i(X,\operatorname{Tot}^\bullet\mathcal{G})$ expanding $H^i(X,\mathcal{F})\simeq\mathbb{H}^i(X,\mathcal{G}^\bullet)$.
- working row-wise and then column-wise leads to certain spectral sequences which converges to the total complex. (Well this argument is a bit backward but still shows the relationship between a bicomplex and its total complex).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The key point seems to always be "passing to the total complex", as you also suggest in the second part of your answer. Yet, taking total complexes is usually something that only appears in the proofs, but not in the statements of propositions. It is not considered as a part of the functorial framework which is usually phrased in terms of spectral sequences and such and I am having a hard time defending their use in mathematical expositions with my colleagues...

Comment: @AkimEismann What do you mean by "It is not considered as a part of the functorial framework" ? Note that the total complex generalizes the mapping cone. Also that it correspond via Dold-Kan to the diagonal of a bisimplicial set...